# Remove Bluetooth from BLE state

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to enable Bluetooth programmatically in my Android app.

```
adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {
  adapter.enable();
}
```

However, sometimes (**not always**) I get in the console the following message: "BT is in BLE_ON State". Considering that my connection should not be BLE, how can I get rid of it?

Useful information: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a0b91d7%5E!/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the source code, it does not appear to be adjustable from the API. It seems like sometimes, the service (Bluetooth Service) will enter a BT LE only state. Even more interestingly if you look at the source code of BluetoothAdapter.getState() on API level 23, the framework treats this "internal state" as a off public state. So maybe this is a transitionary state that takes place first and maybe a few moment later non-LE functionality is enabled (There is no documentation on this just a shot in the dark).

Furthermore, if you look at the source code from API 25 and beyond, the method enable doesn't check state any more and is simply a asynchronous pass through to the underlying Bluetooth Service. Poking around the source code I found two methods regarding enabling/disabling BLE, respectively enableBLE and disableBLE().

This methods are public, but hidden to the outside world. It wouldn't be hard to write some reflection code that will call these methods in a few lines but I'd definitely recommend heavily researching using another approach and using this as a last resort. I say this because enable() will try to turn on Bluetooth Services on the device without the user being explicitly aware of whats taking place. This is a potentially dangerous methods and is included in the public Bluetooth Framework for setting apps and widget. I'd recommend using the "android way" to enable Bluetooth by requesting it from the system. This could also possibly help fix your problem.